# sys_log - entries repeat them self very often

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I have a TYPO3 6.2 running. today, I took a look in the `sys_log` table and found many entries written in a very short time like:

> "10:34:25     praktikant@LIVE     DB      Aktualisieren       Record 'Kontaktformular
>   Online-Demo' (tt_content:19697) was updated. (Online). (msg#1.2.10)"

This records repeats him self approx ten times with the same timestamp.

another example:

> "10:29:24     praktikant@LIVE     DB      Aktualisieren       Record '[Kein Titel]'
>   (tt_content:19696) was updated. (Online). (msg#1.2.10)"

and this record repeats him self again twelf times, with the same timestamp.

It is not connected to this user, others have this too.

Is that normal? will blow up this table very fast.

Comment: Do you have workspaces enabled? Probably you have any extensions which registered a hook on editing records and those fire the event multiple times for any reason? This is definitely not normal.

Comment: mhh, good question. workspaces are not active.

i just use a hook for kind of preview
\TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutViewDrawItemHookInterface

well, other extensions like news, gridelements or formhandler have hooks too - i guess.